# Using wp_dropdown_pages on Wordpress global options page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress theme options page with some text values for the user to input. This works fine.

What I'm struggling with is this final step of getting the user to select a page to use as a link in the website header.

I've got as far as making the drop down list of pages appear, but Im not sure how to get this to save permenantly, and how to get the value out.

Here is the relevent part of my Functions.php file:

```
/**
 * Global fields
 */
//Custom Theme Settings
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_gcf_interface');

function add_gcf_interface() {
    add_options_page('Quick access bar', 'Quick access bar', '8', 'functions', 'editglobalcustomfields');
}

function editglobalcustomfields() {
    ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Quick access bar fields</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>

    <p><strong>Phone number:</strong><br />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('phonenum'); ?>" /></p>

    <p><strong>Email address:</strong><br />
    <input type="text" name="emailaddress" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('emailaddress'); ?>" /></p>

    <p><strong>Choose page link 1:</strong><br />
    <?php wp_dropdown_pages( array( 
    'name' => 'qab_link1[whatever_page]', 
    'show_option_none' => __( '— Select —' ), 
    'option_none_value' => '0', 
    'selected' => $options['whatever_page'] 
    )); ?>

    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save and publish" /></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="phonenum,emailaddress" />

    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` parameter is what you'll use to get it's value with the `get_option` function. Try altering your code to

```
<?php wp_dropdown_pages( array( 
    'name' => 'whatever_page', 
    'show_option_none' => __( '— Select —' ), 
    'option_none_value' => '0', 
    'selected' => get_option('whatever_page'),
    )); ?>
```

In the name you'll use `whatever_page`, so you can catch the value of it with `get_option('whatever_page')`. Use that in `selected` parameter to retrieve the actual value and make it's `<option>` selected.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but I've done what you suggested and if I select a page in the dropdown box, and then I press the "Save and Publish" button, the drop down box goes back to its default value of "- Select -" ?

Comment: Ah! Sorry just realised I should add 'whaterver_page' to the values on the last hidden input type at the bottom. It works! Many thanks.